# How to include non-editable Text in TextInput?

Tags: react-native, react-native-textinput

**Summary**

I want to have text next to the `TextInput`'s value. This text should not be editable but also needs to be responsive, i.e., it moves as the content length of the TextInput changes so that is always X characters after the `TextInput`'s value.

**Current code**

1. Having adjacent `TextInput` and `Text` components does not result in responsive behavior.

[image: Non-responsive Text field]

```
<View style={{flexDirection:"row"}}>
    <TextInput
        defaultValue={stringValue}
        {...props}
    />
    <Text>%</Text>
</View>
```

2. Modifying `stringValue` to add extra text means that it can be edited by the user.

[image: Nested text can be edited by the user]

```
newStringValue = stringValue + "%";

return (
    <View style={{flexDirection:"row"}}>
        <TextInput
            defaultValue={newStringValue}
            {...props}
        />
        <Text>%</Text>
    </View>
);
```

**Desired behavior**

1. The text should move as the length of `TextInput`'s value changes.
2. The text is not editable and the cursor in `TextInput` cannot move through the adjacent text.

[image: Desired responsive non-editable Text adjacent to TextInput]

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like utilizing `onChangeText`, checking the passed in value and editing it according to your needs? The user will be able to delete the percent sign, but it will reappear immediately.